# How to update rownames in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, merge

I have 3 data frames with three variables each and the name of the player

```
a <- rnorm(16, 3, 2)
b <- rnorm(16, 1, 3)
c <- rpois(16, 3)
year <- c(rep(2015, 5), rep(2016, 5), rep(2017, 6))
player <- c("Alex", "CT", "Bill", "Brian", "Collin", "Chez", "Adam", "Danny III", "Lee", "Chris",
            "Erik", "Axel", "Louis", "Justin", "Dustin", "Johnson")

df_1 <- data.frame(player, year, a, b, c)

d <- rnorm(16, 3, 2)
e <- rnorm(16, 1, 3)
f <- rpois(16, 3)
year <- c(rep(2015, 5), rep(2016, 5), rep(2017, 6))
player <- c("Alexander", "C.T.", "Bill", "Brian", "Collin", "Chez", "Adam", "Danny IV", "Lee", "Chris",
            "Erik", "Axel", "Louis", "Justin", "Dustin", "Johnson")

df_2 <- data.frame(player, year, d, e, f)

g <- rnorm(16, 3, 2)
h <- rnorm(16, 1, 3)
i <- rpois(16, 3)
year <- c(rep(2015, 5), rep(2016, 5), rep(2017, 6))
player <- c("Alex", "CT", "Bill", "Brian", "Collin", "Chez", "Adam", "Danny III", "Lee", "Chris",
            "Erik", "Axel", "Louis", "Justin", "Dustin", "Johnson")

df_3 <- data.frame(player, year, g, h, i)
```

This data frame contains the name of the player corresponding to each data set of variables.
For example, Alex is the same as Alexander in variables from d to f, and it is the same as Alex in observations from g to i. Danny III is named Danny IV in variables from d to f and it is named Danny III in variables from g to i.

```
a_to_c <- c("Alex", "CT", "Danny III")
d_to_f <- c("Alexander", "C.T.", "Danny IV")
g_to_i <- c("Alex", "CT", "Danny III")

names_palyer <- data.frame(a_to_c, d_to_f, g_to_i)
```

I want to merge the three data frames by year and player into a single data frame. I need to use the information from "names_player" to correctly match the player with the data
I did this example for simplicity, in reality, I have thousand of observations so I need to find a way to automatically match the player's name so I can have a single data frame with the information of the three data frames.

Comment: Thanks for point that out. I update the code.

Comment: In fact, I am expecting to have a left join using df_1 as baseline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize the output ('out') as the first data ('df_1'). Loop over the index of columns of 'names_palyer' (excluding the last column), `get` the value of 'df_' object corresponding (incrementing 1 - `i + 1` - assuming objects are named as `df_1`, `df_2` etc.), then select a subset of columns of 'names_palyer' (`keydat)`, use `match` to get the index of matching values with 'player' column of 'tmp' data.  Replace the 'player' to the first column values of 'keydat' based on index, then do the `merge` (left join - `all.x = TRUE`), and at end, change the output 'player' that `match` to keydat' column to second column values of 'keydat' (so that it would be useful for the next iteration)

```
out <- df_1
for(i in 1:(ncol(names_palyer)-1)) {
     tmp <- data.table::copy(get(paste0('df_', i + 1)))
     keydat <- names_palyer[c(i, i + 1)]
     keydat <- keydat[keydat[[2]] %in% tmp$player,, drop = FALSE]
     i1 <- match(keydat[[2]], tmp$player, nomatch = 0) 
     
     tmp$player[i1] <- keydat[[1]]
     print(tmp)
     out <- merge(out, tmp, by = c('player', 'year'), all.x = TRUE)
     i2 <- match(keydat[[1]], out$player, nomatch = 0)
     
     out$player[i2] <- keydat[[2]] 
}
```

-output

```
out
      player year           a           b c         d           e f          g           h i
1       Adam 2016  0.03587367 -0.57907496 3 5.1149009  2.47064240 2  2.3325348  0.62526907 6
2       Alex 2015  1.27778013  0.05809471 0 4.1932959  4.37934704 0  4.3226737 -0.33523019 5
3       Axel 2017  2.56466723  0.43108713 2 5.9970138 -2.19947169 4  0.9717511  2.05843957 3
4       Bill 2015  2.05594607  3.96167974 3 2.5232810  3.87191286 3  3.1726895  3.43683108 0
5      Brian 2015  3.44690732  0.35032810 4 4.7287671  0.08108714 2  2.8519495 -0.08249603 2
6         CT 2015  5.85679299 -1.57623304 2 3.9653678  1.68389034 3  3.0328709  1.04315644 2
7       Chez 2016  0.73604605 -2.58101736 1 4.0642894  0.04941299 3  5.4688474 -1.82831432 3
8      Chris 2016  0.95621081  2.05206411 4 2.7249987  2.42911270 8 -0.4515070 -2.12097504 0
9     Collin 2015  7.14194691  0.74030236 5 4.7879545  5.41397214 4  1.4835656  0.92897125 2
10 Danny III 2016  4.59832890  0.60355092 5 4.4822495  4.15865653 0  2.4950848  3.31059942 3
11    Dustin 2017  0.26640646 -0.23381080 4 5.3164916  3.67001803 1  0.7011976  2.59135173 4
12      Erik 2017  0.27363760 -4.50110125 3 4.9495033  3.31417537 3  4.1907692  5.57914934 6
13   Johnson 2017  7.12013083  2.52775367 3 1.9192381  4.33916287 2  3.3836699 -2.37444447 3
14    Justin 2017  3.41710305 -3.82843506 4 5.5590782  0.56030426 1  0.1670448  5.99934712 6
15       Lee 2016 -1.02002976 -3.24576311 4 0.9538381 -0.91783716 5  2.5668076 -0.67247680 2
16     Louis 2017  1.94420093  0.47369179 3 2.8249960 -1.28630731 7  3.0070664  1.25132019 5
```

---

With the OP's new data

```
out <- copy(df_1)
for(i in 1:(ncol(names_palyer)-1)) {
     tmp <- data.table::copy(get(paste0('df_', i + 1)))
     keydat <- names_palyer[c(i, i + 1)]
     keydat <- keydat[keydat[[2]] %in% tmp$player,, drop = FALSE]
     i1 <- match(keydat[[2]], tmp$player, nomatch = 0) 
     
     tmp$player[i1] <- keydat[[1]]
     print(tmp)
     out <- merge(out, tmp, by = c('player', 'year'), all.x = TRUE)
     i2 <- match(keydat[[1]], out$player, nomatch = 0)
     
     out$player[i2] <- keydat[[2]][keydat[[1]] %in% out$player] 
}

library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
split.default(out[-(1:2)], sub("\\..*", "", names(out)[-(1:2)])) %>%
   map_dfc(reduce, coalesce)  %>% 
     bind_cols( out[1:2], .)
```

Comment: Thanks for point that out. I update my code. Yes, I need to merge by year and name. Can you explain me how you did to make R recognize that for df_1 we should use column 'a_to_c' of names_player data frame, and for df_2 we should use column 'd_to_f' Thanks for your help

Comment: @PastorSoto your names_palyer data columns are in the same order as df_1', 'df_2', ....  So, we are just looping over the sequence of columns

Comment: When I did it in the sample data it works perfectly but when I did in in the actual data that has a lot more variable and each df_ has different number of variables it gives this warning message. Do you think there is a problem? Warning messages:
1: In tmp$player[i1] <- keydat[[1]] :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
2: In out$player[i2] <- keydat[[2]] :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Comment: @PastorSoto If you can show an example that shows the issue it would be great.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Your answer is useful. Thanks for spending the time to answer my question. I was just trying to understand the code.

Comment: @PastorSoto I understand the issue in your case.  Probably your keydat or `names_palyer` those columns doesn't have all values getting matched as in the input example.  If you have only less number of matches, it is probably better to create a `list` rather than a data.frame as `names_palyer`

Comment: Yes!! I think that's the problem. Can you help me with that?

Comment: @PastorSoto I think for that you may need a second index `i3 <- keydat[[2]] %in% tmp$player; tmp$player[i1] <- keydat[[1]][i3]` and `i4 <- keydat[[1]] %In% out$player;out$player[i2] <- keydat[[2]][i4]`

Comment: @PastorSoto It is not tested.  So there would be some changes to that code

Comment: @PastorSoto I made a small change in the code.  Can you test it now

Comment: I still have the same problem: Warning message:
In out$player[i2] <- keydat[[2]] :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Comment: @PastorSoto can you use `print(i2)` and `print(nrow(keydat))` if there is any mismatch it will show

Comment: @PastorSoto Or if you can update your post with a small example that throws this warning, i can test

Comment: There are some observations that have missing values. Do you think that this might be the problem? In df_1 I have 1068 observations with 498 columns. df_2 960 observations with 6 variables. df_3 1079 observations with 17 variables. ```print(i2)``` gives 278 observations some of them are 0. While ```print(nrow(keydat)))``` gives 278.

Comment: @PastorSoto that would be the issue.   By default if there is not a match, it returns `NA`.  I changed it to `nomatch = 0` i.e. some have NA elements.  But, in R, index starts from 1.  So, we don't use those 0 values. Probably you may need `print(length(i2[i2 != 0]))`and `print(nrow(keydat[[2]]))`

Comment: @PastorSoto if you can update with some example, it would be easier for me to test

Comment: I add the files here. I tried to create a reproducible example but I couldn't https://github.com/sotoblanco/test

Comment: @PastorSoto I will check into that

Comment: @PastorSoto with that data, I didn't notice any error.  But all the dataset have all those columns whih result in duplication of columns i.e. .x and .y suffix

Comment: @PastorSoto Do you want to coalesce those columns later

Comment: Did you get a warning message? Yes. I am taking a weighted average on those columns. I got this: Warning message:
In out$player[i2] <- keydat[[2]] :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Comment: I made a mistake. These are the actual files. Sorry about that. https://github.com/sotoblanco/test_2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231289/discussion-between-pastor-soto-and-akrun).